# Increment and decrement a value depending to these conditions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing

I have a **beb** array of shape (3,8) it represents three lines of 8 bits (1 or 0), a **copiv** array of shape (3,8,2) which represents basically the 8 first pixels of an image with only the Green and Blue value of the RGB. And I have a **mask**, array of boolean of shape (3,8). The value of the mask array is True if Green and Blue values are of different parity, and False if they have the same parity. Here's how they look like (beb, mask and copiv respectively) :

```
beb = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],[0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1],[0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0]]) #shape (3,8)


mask = np.array([[True, False, True, True, True, False, False, True],
                 [True, False, True, True, True, False, False, True],
                 [True, False, True, True, True, False, False, True]]) #shape (3,8)


copiv = np.array([
[[138, 207],[133, 201],[133, 202],[134, 203],[133, 202],[133, 203],[134, 206],[133, 204]],
[[139, 208],[133, 201],[133, 202],[134, 203],[133, 202],[133, 203],[134, 206],[134, 205]],
[[139, 208],[133, 201],[133, 202],[135, 204],[133, 202],[133, 203],[135, 207], [134, 205]]]) # shape (3,8,2)
```

What I want is to increment or decrement the second value of the copiv array, (so the Blue value which is the second value, the first value is the Green value) depending on those conditions :

-When the bit of **beb** array is = 0 and that Green and Blue values are of the same parity (e.g. [1 3] or [6 8], means that in the **copiv** array it would return False, bc same parity) we do nothing.

-When the bit of **beb** array is 0 again, but this time, the parity of Green and Blue are different (e.g. [4 3], means that in the **copiv** array it would return True) then in this case : if Blue is an even value, we increment Blue, if Blue is an odd value, we decrement Blue.

-When the bit of **beb** is 1 now, and if Green and Blue are True in **copiv** array : we do nothing

-And when the bit of **beb** is 1 and that Green and Blue return False , so they have a different parity : if Blue is even we increment it, if it is odd, we decrement it.

Here's my code but the decrement doesn't work :

```
print("COPIV BEOFRE : \n", copiv)


for i in range(beb.shape[0]):
        for j in range(beb.shape[1]):

            if (beb[i][j] == 0):
                for y in range(mask.shape[0]):
                    for z in range(mask.shape[1]):
                        for x in range(copiv.shape[0]):
                                for w in range(copiv.shape[1]):
                                    if (mask[y,z] == True and copiv[x,w,1:3] % 2 == 0):                
                                        copiv[x,w,1:3] += 1                                
                                    elif (copiv[x,w,1:3] % 2 != 0):
                                        copiv[x,w,1:3] -= 1                                                                                       

            elif (beb[i][j] == 1):
                if(mask[y,z] == False and copiv[x,w,1:3] % 2 == 0):
                    copiv[x,w,1:3] += 1                                #increment B
                elif (copiv[x,w,1:3] % 2 != 0):
                    copiv[x,w,1:3] -= 1           #decrement B


print("\nCOPIV AFTER : \n", copiv)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
copiv[...,1] ^= beb^mask
```

Explainer:

One can check that the operation "increment if even, decrement if odd" can be rephrased as "flip lowest bit". That's the `^=` bit in the expression---if the r.h.s. is `1`, if it is `0`, `^=` does nothing.

We can also check that the r.h.s. takes the right value for all 4 cases considered.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goals as follows

```
# first, generate boolean condition array.
cond1 = beb==1  # shape (3,8)

# then, new condition by logical operation
cond2 = np.logical_and(cond1, mask)

# finally, filter indices using boolean array, and assign value
copv[cond2,0] += 100    # 0 index for blue
```